# Can't access to JS function using runat on div element

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have problem on Javascript using `document.getElementById("#divExternUser").style.display = "block";` when i use runat="server"

I have this function:

```
function displayHideShowDivExtern(element) {
switch(element.value) {
    case "S":
        document.getElementById("divOExternS").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("divOExternM").style.display = "none";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("divOExternS").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("divOExternM").style.display = "block";
}
```

}

on my aspx I can't access to my DropDownList elements(in javascript functions) when i put `runat="server"` on div element.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

```
<div id="divOExtern" style="display:block" >
     Extern
       <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOExterna" runat="server"  CssClass="txtBoxLarge" Height="20px"   onchange="javascript:displayHideShowDivOExtern(this)">
            <asp:ListItem Text="S -" Value="S" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="T -" Value="T" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="M -" Value="M" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="O -" Value="O" />
       </asp:DropDownList> 
        <p>
           <div id="divOExternS" style="display:none"  runat="server"  >
                 S
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlS" runat="server"  CssClass="txtBoxLarge" Height="20px"   />
           </div>              
           <div id="divOExternT" style="display:none" runat="server"  >
                 T
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlT" runat="server"  CssClass="txtBoxLarge" Height="20px"   />
           </div>
            <div id="divOExternM" style="display:none" runat="server"  >
                 M
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlM" runat="server"  CssClass="txtBoxLarge" Height="20px"   />
           </div>
           <div id="divOExternO" style="display:none" runat="server"  >
                 O
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtEntities" runat="server"  CssClass="txtBoxLarge" />                                     
           </div>
       </p>
   </div>
```

before use the runat on div, i could access without problems. I cann't undertand why!?

Comment: you shouldn't put a div element inside a p element. Note : it's not related to your problem.

Comment: i change my p with a clear div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't find any element having id named divExternUser or divInternUser in your code. So I created two div's giving them those id's.

Call the ***displayHideShowDivExtern()*** function onchange of the dropdownlist in this way,

```
onchange="displayHideShowDivExtern(this)"
```

***HTML :***

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOExterna" runat="server"  CssClass="txtBoxLarge" Height="20px" onchange="displayHideShowDivExtern(this)" >
    <asp:ListItem Text="S -" Value="S" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="T -" Value="T" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="M -" Value="M" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="O -" Value="O" />
</asp:DropDownList> 

<div id="divExternUser">This is divExternUser</div>
<div id="divInternUser">This is divInternUser</div>
```

***javaScript :***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function displayHideShowDivExtern(element) {
        alert();
        switch (element.value) {
            case "S":
                document.getElementById("divExternUser").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("divInternUser").style.display = "none";
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById("divExternUser").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("divInternUser").style.display = "block";
         }
     }
</script>
```

So at the end of the day, whether you use ***runat="server"*** or not, you can access the element from client side using the id of that element.

Because, though it's a server side control, it is ultimately going to be rendered into pure HTML element and then converted into DOM element for manipulation at client side. So you are going to get that using it's id.

**Note :**  If your js code is in an external file you must add reference of that script into your page so that you can use it.

```
<script src="pathToYourJSFile/yourjsFile.js"></script>
```

*That's it. It'll work.*

Comment: So sorry, but i write an old code, i edit my question.

Comment: change the id's corresponding to their respective elements. It'll still work.

Comment: @kaub0st3r do update your question carefully. There's no element having divExternS or divExternM yet.

Comment: Yes, is working thanks, but i can't understand why works when uses the javascript in code(aspx page) but not on a .js file.

Comment: @kaub0st3r, Check the Note section i've added into my answer.

Comment: Nop, not working on extern file :\. And i use others functions on same page, but the others elements not have the runat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65514/discussion-between-ashad-shanto-and-kaub0st3r).

Answer (score 2):

because the `runat=server` property you can access the div by using:`"<%=divid.ClientID%>"`
try change your code as following:

```
function displayHideShowDivExtern(element) {
switch(element.value) {
    case "S":
        document.getElementById("<%=divExternUser.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("<%=divInternUser.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("<%=divExternUser.ClientID%>").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("<%=divInternUser.ClientID%>").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: yes, had already used that. I i catch the same error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'style': object is null or undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try adding attribute ClientIdMode = 'static' in div tag.